# How to check if svn external is set for a repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have an old repository (SVN) and I am not sure if `svn external` is set for it, and if yes.. for what path?

Is there a way to find that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry for being so restless... Did a little research and got the answer ...
These properties can be viewed through the following ways:

1. Right click on the working copy -> Tortoise SVN -> Properties
2. In the .svn folder, browse through the `entries` file.

Cheers!!

Comment: But is `TortoiseSVN == It's own Repo Server`. I guess it's a thin client to facilitate the operations around your SVN repo. Let me know if I have gone horribly wrong here...

Answer (score 12):

or you could do

```
svn propget svn:externals -R
```